# Quartz trigger state is not persisting on server start

Tags: quartz-scheduler

We have a requirement to pause a job before application maintenance. We are using Quartz 2.2.1 in cluster. Database is oracle.

I have developed a screen with "Pause" functionality. I observed that "pause" works fine until I start the server again. The moment I start server, TRIGGER_STATE of QRTZ_TRIGGERS table resets to "WAITING".

Can anyone please provide a hint.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Rgds - Roy

Answer (score 0):

If you have set overwriteExistingJobs=true (note that default value is false) then each time server starts, it loads the jobs/triggers from the configuration file and replaces existing ones (that have the same job/trigger names), therefore overwriting triggers and their states too  as in your case.

You could try to set overwriteExistingJobs=false in the SchedulerFactoryBean. This however may not be convenient for you, since if you ever change job configuration in the server, the existing jobs with old configuration will remain in the database.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
    ....
    <property name="overwriteExistingJobs" value="false"/>
    <property name="triggers">
        <list>
            ....
        </list>
    </property>
    ....
</bean>
```