# Quartz schedular job state updation

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

How to update `qrtz_triggers` set `trigger_state` as "`PAUSED`" at Tomcat Startup.At tomcat startup it is setting the trigger as "`WAITING`".

Adding further details:-
Property overWriteExistingJobs=true does update the firing time as defined in the xml file. But it also updates the job status from PAUSED to WAITING,If i have PAUSED the job.I mean it changes the previous job state which i have set. 
My objective is to keep the previous job status and update the new firing time as defined in the xml file.
I mean if the cron changes in the xml file.It should update the new firing time but it should not change the previous tigger Status if it was paused let it be pause,not set the new value to waiting. Thanks in advance

Comment: is there any relevant code to show?

Comment: Is your question duplicate of [Quartz trigger state is not persisting on server start](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26586089/quartz-trigger-state-is-not-persisting-on-server-start)?

Comment: Actually When tomcat starts it sets the trigger as TRIGGER_STATE column as  WAITING in the QRTZ_TRIGGERS table.But I want to set the status as PAUSED in the QRTZ_TRIGGERS  table

Answer (score 0):

Use `scheduler.pauseJob()` or `scheduler.pauseTrigger()`.

Look here for more information:[Quartz Docs](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.2.0/org/quartz/core/QuartzScheduler.html#pauseJob%28org.quartz.JobKey%29)